# How to create page hierarchy in Odoo?

Tags: python, url-rewriting, odoo, odoo-8

In Odoo, pages are created with url **/page/page-name** and basically it creates a template with id **website.page-name** and going to **/page/website.page-name** redirects to **/page/page-name**.

I need to create a page category with subpages and have the url look like **/category-name/subpage-name** (e.g. **example-website.com/films/sherlock**). Is this possible **without** having to define a web controller that renders the page? Is it possible to map **/page/category-name.subpage-name**  to **/category-name/subpage-name**?